# Error: Use of unidentified type 'Vertex'

Tags: c++

Here is the code;

```
class Vertex;

class CPD
{
private:
    width;

public:
    void initialize()
    {   .
        .
        .
    }

    void updateTable(LinkedList<Vertex*>* parents)
    {
        node<Vertex *> *ptr = parents->getHead();
        int W = 1;
        while (ptr)
        {
            W *= ((ptr->data)->getStates())->getSize();
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
        width = W;
        initialize();
    }
};
```

However, I'm getting a "use of undefined type 'Vertex'" error within the while loop in the first statement, although I have given a class Vertex prototype at the beginning. Some help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You need the complete definition of Vertex, not just a forward declaration.

Comment: well, the 'Vertex' class itself uses the 'CPD' class, so ill be back at square one...

Comment: `updateTable()` should not be inline. Move it into an implementation file. Then you'll be fine.

Comment: Your does not compiles. Your declaration of `width` is broken. Put the type also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as only a forward declaration of Vertex is given, the compiler does not know anything about this class and its members. How could it?

Nevertheless, you do not need these details for the declaration of CPD. The compiler simply has to know that the class Vertex *exists* for understanding the function signatures.

This way, you can avoid the interdependency of Vertex and CPD. As @kec pointed out, the solution would be to move the definition of updateTable() to another file, in which the full definition of Vertex is included.

File Vertex.hpp:

```
class Vertex {
  // declaration here
};
```

File CPD.hpp:

```
class Vertex;

class CPD {
  void updateTable(LinkedList<Vertex*>* parents);
  // ...
};
```

File CPD.cpp:

```
#include "Vertex.hpp"

void CPD::updateTable(LinkedList<Vertex*>* parents){
  // definition here
}
```